# Regexp_like with placeholders perl

Tags: perl, oracle

I need a query to pick up names that has any suffix from a-z. I know regexp_like can do this. But how should I use regexp_like with place holders?

`select id_name from name_table where regexp_like(name,'REM_45485[a-z]$');`

How should I use place holders in this  ? Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Place holders? Can you give an example of what this query should select and what it should not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do:

```
select id_name from name_table where regexp_like(name, ?);
```

If only part of the regexp comes from the placeholder, use string concatenation:

```
select id_name from name_table where regexp_like(name, ? || '[a-z]$');
```